# adding dataset as reader of another dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

We want to add the intermediate data set as reader of the source dataset in Bigquery.
For example,we want to add **data_studio_test** dataset as reader of the **master** dataset?
Please help on how to do this in bigquery.

Comment: Can you describe your use case in more details!

Comment: Actually we want to give access to intermediate dataset instead of source dataset which is in another project.Also we dont want to give access to source project.So,we want to add the intermediate dataset as reader of source dataset so that we dont need to give access to source dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for so called [Authorized Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views)

> Giving a view access to a dataset is also known as creating an authorized view in BigQuery. An authorized view allows you to share query results with particular users and groups without giving them access to the underlying tables. You can also use the view's SQL query to restrict the columns (fields) the users are able to query.
>
> When you create the view, it must be created in a dataset separate from the source data queried by the view. Because you can assign access controls only at the dataset level, if the view is created in the same dataset as the source data, your users would have access to both the view and the data.

For a tutorial on creating an authorized view, see: [Creating an authorized view in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views).

Comment: Yes.i created a view which joins tables from data_studio_test dataset and master dataset in another project.Users get the error as "No Data Set Access and 
Insufficient permissions to the underlying data set" when i create datastudio dashboard with this view query. I think this happened because i didnt give access to master dataset(another project) but i am not supposed to that due to data security.Can we overcome this issue in authorized view?